# imagemagick convert AI file which have transparent layer to PNG

Tags: imagemagick, imagick, imagemagick-convert

I'm not familiar with ai file . I have a AI file which has transparent layer or alpha layer , and I try to convert this file to png with imagemagick:

> > convert -resize '1000x' -density 300 test.ai test.png

ai file url :  pan.baidu.com/s/1eQ9nS4a

I converted image which transparency layer was lost:

url :  assets.baicizhan.com/test_data/test_wrong.jpg

but the correct image should be like this:

url : assets.baicizhan.com/test_data/test_right.jpg

So what is the magic parameter I have to use here?

Comment: I also tried some other options like : -alpha on -contrast , and also failed.

Answer (score 4):

Many people have same problem.
What'is you imagemagick version?
Have you try:

```
convert ai:test.ai -resize '1000x' -density 300 test.png
```

Seems that this command is a patch available from ImageMagick 6.3.7-9 Beta.
In [this discussion](http://www.wizards-toolkit.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=10366) talk about this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes,I have tried ,but it's not correct, and if I want to resize image,I should set "resize" before "ai:test.ai"

Comment: your version of imagemagick? if you are under linux, from shell: convert --version

Comment: my version is ImageMagick 6.6.5-0 . and I tried  "convert -resize '1000x' -density 300 -verbose -colorspace rgb ai:diego_best.ai diego_best.png" . it's not work. I'm trying to research the link you give to me.